# implementation support vectors in python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

```
import sklearn
import numpy
from sklearn.svm import SVC
f=open ('svm_data','r')
X=[]
y=[]
for line in f:
comps=line.strip().split('\t')
x=[float(comps[0]),float(comps[1])]
Y=float(comps[2])
X.append(x)
y.append(y)
X=numpy.asarray(X)
Y=numpy.asarray(Y)
```

how to find the support ectors in this problem.How many support vectors obtained using rbf, linear and polynomial of degree 3 kernels respectively on the given data

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)? Is it something `sklearn` supports or has tools for?

Comment: Please correct the indentation in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not train anything in your code and the number and nature of support-vectors is dependent on data and params.

If you trained your classifier/regressor, you can get them with:

```
sv = clf.support_vectors_
```

as outlined in the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html).

It's an array of shape `[n_SV, n_features]`.

Complete example from the docs:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X, y) 

print(clf.support_vectors_)
```

Comment: maybe worth adding `clf.n_support_`? as this literally holds number of support vectors (per class)?